# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils.SessionState'

Tags: streamlit

File "C:\Users\welleah\Desktop\traffic_flow_counter-master\app\streamlit-app.py", line 10, in 
import utils.SessionState as SessionState
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils.SessionState'

Comment: You can download `SessionState.py` and put it in the same path. Use `import SessionState`

Answer (score 0):

I would rather post this as a comment, but it's a lot of text.

This happens a lot if you have multiple packages in different folders. That's what the PYTHONPATH is there for. To set you PYTHONPATH do the following:

1. Go to your project folder and execute the following command (depending on your shell):

```
# Linux: 
export PYTHONPATH=$PWD
echo $PYTHONPATH

Command Prompt: 
set PYTHONPATH=%cd%
echo %PYTHONPATH%

Powershell: 
$env:PYTHONPATH=$(Get-Location)
echo $Env:PYTHONPATH
```

More about the PYTHONPATH here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-is-PYTHONPATH-environment-variable-in-Python